# Transparent background for modally presented viewcontroller

Tags: swift, parse-platform, ios8.1

I am using Parse & ParseUI.
I want my PFLoginViewController subclass to have a transparent background. In the future, I want to lay a blurred view over the background.

But.... Once the animate-in of the PFLoginViewController is done, the background turns black... Whilst during the animation the background was transparent.

```
func presentLogin() {
    var loginViewController = LoginViewController()
    var signupViewController = SignUpViewController()

    loginViewController.fields = .UsernameAndPassword | .LogInButton | .PasswordForgotten | .SignUpButton | PFLogInFields.DismissButton
    signupViewController.fields = .UsernameAndPassword | .Email | .DismissButton | .SignUpButton
    loginViewController.delegate = self
    loginViewController.logInView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    loginViewController.logInView.opaque = false
    signupViewController.delegate = self

    loginViewController.signUpController = signupViewController

    self.presentViewController(loginViewController, animated: true) { () -> Void in
        //
    }
}
```

My logincontroller's used subclass:

```
class LoginViewController: PFLogInViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var _nmcLogoLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let userName = SettingsManager.userName
        let password = SettingsManager.password

        self.logInView.usernameField.text = userName
        self.logInView.passwordField.text = password

        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("LoginViewBranding", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? UIView

        self.logInView.logo = _nmcLogoLabel

    }

}
```

How can I make it transparent?

P.s. Applying the clearColor to the backgroundColor in the subclass makes no difference

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Fixed it.

The problem was that presentViewController does not keep the view that I was covering.

```
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
```

did the trick.

Comment: can you also comment the code for "pushViewController" .

Comment: Working solution !!

Comment: this is the secret!

Comment: But that will not add the presented controller to the responder chain

Comment: If use modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext, after dismiss view controller, viewWillAppear of parent viewController not being called. Is any way to fix this?

Comment: This helped me while working with UIKit and SwiftUI

Answer (score 56):

Part of the solution is hidden in the question. You need three lines to make the background transparent, viz. `isOpaque = false` `backgroundColor = .clear` & set the `modalPresentationStyle`

Here's the full solution. In the calling View Controller, call this function:

```
func presentModal() {
    let modalController = ModalViewController()
    modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    present(modalViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And in `ModalViewController`'s `viewDidLoad()`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.isOpaque = false
    view.backgroundColor = .clear // try other colors, say: .white or black with Alpha etc.
}
```

Comment: this worked for me when I set the code in the `Init`, not in the `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: @NitinNain, I set view.alpha = 0.35 but all view controller's control also set with alpha and look blur

Answer (score 23):

same as the selected answer but visually through IB:

[image]

Comment: You need also to set up the presented controller as Nitin Nain answer

Answer (score 7):

*I have two view controller 1st login & 2nd forgot password. Initially, the login screen has been visible on the tap of forgot password button, forgot password screen will be present over the login screen with a transparent background.*

**In the Login screen, I have used following code for forgotButtonAction to present forgotPasswordViewController**

```
   let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "forgotPasswordViewController") as! forgotPasswordViewController
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**And also in the forgotPasswordViewController, Under the ViewDidLoad method, I have to change the view background color and opaque state through the following code**

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.isOpaque = false
    view.backgroundColor = .clear
   }
```

Comment: This is great `view.backgroundColor = .clear`

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still struggling with a transparent background I found this solution some time ago - I can't remember where but still works fine with the latest Xcode & Swift.

```
ContactListViewController2: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
    self.transitioningDelegate = self
}
```