# Show and hide modal when requesting data from API

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a few requests to my API that, while it's making the request, I want to show a fullscreen modal with a spinner in the middle that goes overtop the current scene.

I have set up a scene in my storyboard and I've given that scene a controller:

```
class LoadingViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

In my other controller, I have the following:

```
class SignInViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Properties

    @IBOutlet weak var submitButton: UIButton!

    // MARK: Actions

    @IBAction func onSubmit(_ sender: Any) {
        // How do I show LoadingViewController as a modal here?
        // Later, how do I hide it?
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

As I commented above, when the user clicks on the Submit button, I want to show the fullscreen modal over that controller. Then, when the API returns data, I want to hide the modal.

How can I show and hide the `LoadingViewController` as a modal overtop the `SignInViewController`?

Comment: Design your own LoadingViewController, present it while with luck because as far as i know, iOS will make the background black of the background so you won't be able to make the LoadingViewController background transparent. Take a reference of the modal you're showing, and dismiss it while network call recieved.

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669699/transparent-background-for-modally-presented-viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that will create a simple loader view on top of the presented view,

First, we need to create a class that is responsible for adding/removing an `activityIndicator`

```
class AppLoaderView : UIView{

    fileprivate
    lazy var circularProgressIndicator : UIActivityIndicatorView = {
        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
        activityIndicator.center = self.center
        activityIndicator.style = .gray
        activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        self.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        return activityIndicator
    }()


    func showSpinning() {
        setupConstraints()
        circularProgressIndicator.startAnimating()
    }

    private
    func setupConstraints() {
        let xCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .centerX,
                                                   relatedBy: .equal, toItem: circularProgressIndicator,
                                                   attribute: .centerX,
                                                   multiplier: 1,
                                                   constant: 0)
        self.addConstraint(xCenterConstraint)

        let yCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .centerY,
                                                   relatedBy: .equal, toItem: circularProgressIndicator,
                                                   attribute: .centerY,
                                                   multiplier: 1,
                                                   constant: 0)
        self.addConstraint(yCenterConstraint)
    }


    func removeLoading() {
        circularProgressIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }

}
```

Now we will create an extension on viewController, that has two methods one for showing the *`LoaderView`* and one for removing it,

```
extension UIViewController{

    private var loaderView : AppLoaderView?{

        if let view =  self.view.subviews.first(where: { $0 is AppLoaderView}) as? AppLoaderView { return view }
        let view = AppLoaderView(frame: self.view.frame)
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        view.isHidden = true
        return view
    }


    func showLoaderView(){
        if let view = loaderView  {

            self.view.addSubview(view)
            self.view.bringSubviewToFront(view)
            view.isHidden = false
            view.clipsToBounds = true
            view.layoutIfNeeded()
            view.showSpinning()

        }

    }

    func removeLoaderView(){
        if let view = loaderView{
            view.removeLoading()
            view.removeFromSuperview()
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

That's it, now with your example you can call `self.showLoaderView()` when the button clicked, and once the API call returns you will call `self.removeLoaderView()`.

Add these somewhere in your project, and on any viewController you can call these methods to `show/hide` your `loaderView`.

Answer (score 0):

To use a transparent background with the presented view controller, set `modalPresentationStyle = .custom` in the initializer of your `LoadingViewController` class.

To use a custom transition with the presented view controller, set the  `transitioningDelegate` property of your `LoadingViewController` class and implement the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` and `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`.

For example:

```
class LoadingViewController: UIViewController {

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)

            transitioningDelegate = self        // Required for a custom transition.
            modalPresentationStyle = .custom    // Required for a transparent background.
    }

    // Other setup in your class...
}

extension LoadingViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    public func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController,
                                    presenting: UIViewController,
                                    source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return self
    }

    public func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return self
    }
}

extension LoadingViewController: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.25
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        if isBeingPresented {

            let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to)!
            toView.alpha = 0

            transitionContext.containerView.addSubview(toView)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                           animations: {
                toView.alpha = 1
            }, completion: { (_) in
                transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
            })

        } else {

            let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from)!

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                           animations: {
                fromView.alpha = 0
            }, completion: { (_) in
                fromView.removeFromSuperview()
                transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can just present and dismiss your custom `LoadingViewController` normally:

```
@IBAction func onSubmit(_ sender: Any) {

    // Present loading view controller.
    self.present(LoadingViewController(), animated: true)

    // Dismiss later in the callback of your API call...
    // API.request {
    //     self.dismiss(animated: true)
    // }
}
```

This can achieve the effect you're looking for:
[image: custom transition demo]