# How to present unique UITabBarControllers in Swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I'm working on a project that has two different UITabBarControllers to represent two different states of the app. I can set the first UITabBarController once a user logs in and present the second when a button is pressed. However, I'm getting odd behavior when navigating within the second UITabBarController.

This is how I set the main tab bar.

```
let mainTabBar = MainTabBarController()
let mainMode = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainTabBar)
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = mainMode
```

I use an identical method to navigate to the second tab bar.

```
let secondaryTabBar = SecondaryTabBarController()
let hiddenMode = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondaryTabBar)
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = hiddenMode
```

However, when using the secondary UITabBarController, I see views from the main UITabBarController when navigating to an AVCaptureSession. More specifically, I see the last view (from which the secondaryTabBar is set) from the mainTabBar under the modal presentation of the capture session.  Here's the problem point:

```
    let captureSession = CameraViewController()        
    navigationController?.present(captureSession, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the modalPresentationStyle of the CameraViewController to .overCurrentContext and that solved the issue. Got it from here: [Transparent background for modally presented viewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669699/transparent-background-for-modally-presented-viewcontroller)