# How to make Screen Background Data visible in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I want to make the screen like the following.

[image]

In source class, I write this code and push to side menu controller.

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SidemenuController")as! SidemenuController

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
```

I write the following code in destination controller view did load method but just color opacity is decreased data is not visible.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.view.backgroundColor = self.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "BE8790").withAlphaComponent(0.4)
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can achieve that using `push`, you need to present modally instead. See [Transparent background for modally presented viewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669699/transparent-background-for-modally-presented-viewcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.withAlphaComponent(0.4)`

Try this  Adjust the number as needed

```
self.view.alpha = 0.5
```

Comment: Value of type 'SidemenuController' has no member 'backgroundView'

Comment: @ghrixghrix Please read my answer, I said use self.backgroundview is whatever view you are using as teh background. If it is the main view use the main view -> self.view.alpha = 0.5

Answer (score 0):

You show present your SideViewController. Maybe custom how it shows

```
 let sideVC = // Your init
 sideVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
 present(sideVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In your SideViewController,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.alpha = 0.5
        view.backgroundColor = // Your color
        tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
}
```